# How to recognise buttons clicked in a particular sequence?

Tags: python, qt, events, sequence, pyside

I have a handful of `QPushButtons` which play different .wav files either on mouse click or when a keyboard shortcut (single letter key) is pressed.

I would like to know if there is a way to recognise when the buttons are clicked in a particular sequence, and then play a different sound? The closest I have been able to get so far was using setShortcut to assign a sound to play when a particular key sequence is pressed, but this only works using keys which are not assigned as pushbutton shortcuts.

I am new to Python (and PySide) so I'm not sure whether this is even possible.

Comment: You would have to manually record the order of key presses and choose to play a sound based on that sequence. You'd have to decide how long to wait after the first key press for a second key press in case the user is trying to input a sequence, or just playing a single press sound.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an event that is fired if and only if a sequence of other events has fired in between in the correct order. I don't know of any inbuilt framework in Qt that does it except for pressing sequences of keys. So you must build this for yourself. It's not that difficult, you can for example listen to each button then calling a method with a certain number (the position in the sequence of events you are interested in) then checking that you are having positions in this sequence in strictly increasing order (otherwise reseting) and if you arrive at a certain length firing your own event.

Example:

```
from functools import partial
from PySide import QtGui

class MyEvent():

    def __init__(self):
        self.last_level = 0
        self.top_level = 3

    def update(self, level):
        if level == self.last_level + 1:
            self.last_level += 1
            if level == self.top_level:
                print('beep')
                self.last_level = 0
        else:
            if level == 1:
                self.last_level = level
            else:
                self.last_level = 0

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

e = MyEvent()

w = QtGui.QWidget()
l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(w)

b1 = QtGui.QPushButton('Button 1')
b1.clicked.connect(partial(e.update, 1))
l.addWidget(b1)


b2 = QtGui.QPushButton('Button 2')
b2.clicked.connect(partial(e.update, 3))
l.addWidget(b2)

b3 = QtGui.QPushButton('Button 3')
b3.clicked.connect(partial(e.update, 2))
l.addWidget(b3)

w.show()

app.exec_()
```

This prints "beep" if buttons 1, 3, 2 are pressed in this order.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the buttons in a [button-group](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html), so that activating a button sends an identifier that can be recorded by a central signal handler. The identifiers can then be added together to form a sequence that is looked up in a dictionary of sound files.

Here's a simple demo:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        self.buttonGroup = QtGui.QButtonGroup(self)
        for column in range(3):
            identifier = column + 1
            button = QtGui.QPushButton('&%d' % identifier, self)
            self.buttonGroup.addButton(button, identifier)
            layout.addWidget(button, 0, column)
        self.edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.edit.setReadOnly(True)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked[int].connect(self.handleButtons)
        self._sounds = {
            '123': 'moo.wav',  '132': 'bark.wav',
            '213': 'meow.wav', '231': 'baa.wav',
            '312': 'oink.wav', '321': 'quack.wav',
            }
        self._sequence = ''

    def handleButtons(self, identifier):
        self._sequence += str(identifier)
        if len(self._sequence) == 3:
            self.edit.setText(self._sounds.get(self._sequence, ''))
            self._sequence = ''

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 300, 100)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```